# How to DRY up Ruby initialize method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application I have this class:

```
class Plan

  attr_reader :name, :id, :amount, :interval, :maximum, :features

  def initialize(id, name, amount, interval, maximum, features)
    @id = id
    @name = name
    @amount = amount
    @interval = interval
    @maximum = maximum
    @features = features
  end

  ...

end
```

Is there a way to DRY up this class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```
def initialize(*args)
  @id, @name, @amount, @interval, @maximum, @features = args
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind replacing *attr_reader* with *attr_accessor*, then you can use this, which will catch up the invalid attributes that may be provided when creating a new object:

```
class Plan
  attr_accessor :name, :id, :amount, :interval, :maximum, :features

  def initialize params = {}
     params.each { |key, value| send "#{key}=", value }
  end
end
```

Comment: This also changes signature of the initializer.  It used positional parameters before.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind `attr_accessor` instead of `attr_reader`, then you can use Struct. That's exactly what it does: take care of all the boilerplate in the initializer.

```
Plan = Struct.new(:name, :id, :amount, :interval, :maximum, :features) do
  # def my_other_methods
  #   ...
  # end
end

plan = Plan.new('Joe', 1, 500)
plan.name # => "Joe"
plan.id # => 1
plan.amount # => 500
plan.interval # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
def initialize(params = {})
  params.each{ |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

what I usually do when I have more than two classes with initializers like this:

```
# initialize.rb
module Initialize
  def initialize(params={})
    params.each do |attr, value|
      public_send("#{attr}=", value)
    end if params
  end
end

# plan.rb
class Plan

  include Initialize

  attr_accessor :name, :id, :amount, :interval, :maximum, :features

  def initialize(id:, name:, amount:, interval:, maximum:, features:)
    # some additional initialization code could go there
    super
  end
end
```

This way individual setters could be made to additionally cleanup data, you can define defaults, or you can delegate some setters.